# Add routing rules in MVC app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing

I am trying to write a rule to map a URL but so for I did not get the results I want. I have this rule so far:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Search", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{product}/{page}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Search", product = UrlParameter.Optional, page = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

using this I can achieve this result so far:

```
 localhost:8493/home/search/myproduct
 localhost:8493/home/search/myproduct/2
```

but i want to do something like this:

```
 localhost:8493/myproduct
```

so this will route to `home/search/myproduct`

I have tried the following but it didn't work:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "DirectSearch", // Route name
            "{product}/{page}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Search", } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

Is there a way to do this?

**Add:**

So Here i added the specific route to map to another action but it doesn't work:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Tuna",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Tuna", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close I think.  This should work;

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Search", // Route name
            "{product}/{page}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Search", product = UrlParameter.Optional, page = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

Just remember that the framework will read the route data from top to bottom and use the first one it finds that matches.  So make sure the more specific routes are listed before the more general ones

**Edit**

[Here's a link to a discussion on custom routing](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2009/02/06/chapter-2-understanding-routing.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. I had that route as well but it was at very bottom. I didn't know it reads from top to bottom but now I do :-)

Comment: Ok I just noticed an issue. so now if I try to go to another action in same/different controller, it takes the controller name as the value for `product`. Do you have any suggestion on how i can get around that? thanks

Comment: This is one of the perils of ultra specific route mapping.  You'll need to write specific routes to match specific needs.

Comment: so I added the specific route in my post. I had to move it up in order to make that work but then if try to use my other route map to search for a product, it doesn't find that maproute because it is looking for `/home/tuna`. Is there a way to add constraints to this?

Comment: I edited my answer with a link to a fairly comprehensive look at custom routing, including how to add constraints and how to debug routes.